# How do I get importrange and jointext to combine 3 name cells into 1 cell on a new worksheet in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

On Wksht A I have cells C5=last name (i.e. Doe), D5=first name (i.e. Jane), E5=first name (i.e. John). This is to cover 2 joint owners (i.e. husband and wife) in our housing complex. I want to import those 3 name cells onto Wksht B, but I want them combined so that it looks like this: B2 & C2 A2 (i.e. Jane & John Doe). I don't want the & to print if E5 is blank, so just: Jane Doe.
As I see it, I need IMPORTRANGE to pull data from Wksht A to Wksht B.
And I need JOINTEXT to merge the 3 cells into 1, because jointext allows me to skip blank cells and put a delimiter between joined cells.
When I try the formula, even without omitting the & when not needed, I just get "formula parse error", even if I try on the same Wksht A. Both of these fail to the error cited:

```
=TEXTJOIN(“ “, true, D2,E2,C2)  
=TEXTJOIN(“ “, true, D2,”&”,E2,C2)
```

I know I should be able to combine textjoin with importrange, but I just can't get it to work. This was my last attempt, for which I got the error cited:

`=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,ImportRange("<SpshtKey>","<WkshtKey>D5"),ImportRange("<SpshtKey>","<WkshtKey>E5"),"& ",ImportRange("<SpshtKey>","<WkshtKey>C5"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two formulas contains "left double quotation mark". This might be the problem as Google Sheets formulas requires strait quotation marks `"` even if the TEXTJOIN official help article includes the other character.

Try the following formulas

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ", true, D2,E2,C2)  
=TEXTJOIN(" ", true, D2,"&",E2,C2)
```